# Longest Increasing Sub-sequence within a vector using recursion?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, c++17

So for my lab I'm attempting to find the longest sequence of numbers within a given vector.

for example, if the numbers you had were `[5, 15, 16, 4, 8, 9, 10]` the longest increasing sub-sequence would be 4, the `4, 8, 9, 10` portion. I have to be able to find this without using loops and using recursion and I've gotten this far, but I can't quite figure out how to hold a variable for the longest sequence and also have a variable for the temporary longest sequence, it just has to return the integer value of the length of the sequence, not the sequence itself. Thank you and any help or critiques are appreciated!

```
int increasing_sequence_recursive(std::vector<int> &numbers, int startIdx) {
    if (startIdx == numbers.size()) {
        return '/0';
    } else if (numbers[startIdx] < numbers[startIdx + 1]) {
        int tempSeq = 1 + increasing_sequence_recursive(numbers, startIdx + 1);
        return tempSeq;
    }
    return increasing_sequence_recursive(numbers, startIdx + 1);
}
```

EDIT:

```
'''
int maxTemp(std::vector<int> &numbers, int startIdx, int maxSoFar) {
    if (startIdx == numbers.size()) {
        return maxSoFar;
    } else if (numbers[startIdx] < numbers[startIdx + 1]) {
        int temp = 1 + maxTemp(numbers, startIdx + 1, maxSoFar);
        if (temp > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = temp;
        }
        temp = 1;
    } else {
        return maxTemp(numbers, startIdx + 1, maxSoFar);
    }
}
'''
```

I created this helper function to do the main recursion but for some reason the temp value is never resetting so the value is basically the added length of both sequences.

Comment: Define what you mean by "longest sequence of numbers". P.S. What is "`'/0'`"?

Comment: Create a helper recursive function that passes the max found so far as a reference.

Comment: basically I just mean a sequence of numbers that are consecutively increasing, like in the example I gave, it was the numbers 4,8,9,10. So basically the length of the longest amount of increasing numbers in the order they're given, so I'd have a temp variable that stored three for the three increasing numbers 5, 15, 16 at the beginning but the next one which would be 4 would return because there's more consecutive increasing numbers in the second case with 4,8,9,10.

The /0 was a null character I was using at the time.

Comment: There is nothing in your requirements that restricts creating another recursive function.  `int increasing_sequence_recursive(std::vector<int> &numbers, int startIdx, int &maxSoFar)` and have `increasing_sequence_recursive(std::vector<int> &numbers, int startIdx)` call that function with `maxSoFar` set to 0.  The real recursion is done in that secondary recursive function, and that secondary function is updating `maxSoFar`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I created a helper function but have seemingly created a flaw where it never reaches a point where the temp value resets.

Comment: Your `maxTemp` function fails to return a value for all code paths.  For example, `else if (numbers[startIdx] < numbers[startIdx + 1])` fails to return a value.  Second, I mentioned to pass maxTemp as a reference, and update that reference.